MinGW empty output from macro dump command
The switches -dM -E -x c++ /dev/null work very well with my installation of arm-gcc 7.3.1 (and, also, 13.2.1) to generate a list of compiler-provided macros:
#define __cpp_init_captures 201304L
#define __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL 4
#define __ATOMIC_RELEASE 3
// ...

That's in Git Bash on Windows.
With MinGW 13.2.0 using several variations of those switches, it doesn't work.
I've tried msys64/mingw32/bin/g++.exe -E -dM -x c++ /dev/null, I've tried using an empty.cpp instead of /dev/null, and I've tried echo | into - stdin mode. I've also tried calling the gcc.exe executable instead of g++, passing -x c, and omitting -x in the case of a real filename. I've even tried running from PowerShell instead of Git Bash to see if there's a stdout difference.
In every case, there is a silent failure and nothing is output. The only (useless) clue I have as to MinGW's error state is
$ echo $?
1

If I try to pass -o output.c, then output.c is never generated.

Does your GCC 13.2.0 work at all? It seems strange to me that it returns 1 for such a simple case. -- Did you check that you actually call the front-end driver? -- Why do you bother about 13.2.0 (there are newer release versions)? -- Did you consider that you might have found an error? And did you do your research at Gnu's web site about this possibility? What did it reveal? -- Please [edit] your question to add clarifications.

@thebusybee it does indeed work. How would I determine that I'm calling the correct front-end (what's the naming difference)? I'm calling the same compiler I'm using to build the actual binary and that part works fine.
